# Discovering REST Service in java

Tags: java, spring, rest, wadl

Hi I am working with a REST based service. I have a simple REST Service and my client is exposing it via simple HTTP and I am consuming that service, but I want to discover the definition of REST service. I just want it like how SOAP WSDL works for consumer it exposes it contracts to the client side , same thing I need it here. I have gone through with many API like I have read about WADL , RSDL also but didn't get proper idea how to start. Is their any video or open source API which describes the same please share.

Comment: By "discover", do you mean generate all the client code?

Comment: yes I need all the methods and their description with the parameters as how we are getting when we are consuming any SOAP service.

Comment: May be you can use cxf's wadl2java generator and in cxf  you can access the wadl using <your-url>?_wadl

Comment: IIRC, unlike WSDL in SOAP, WADL/RSDL in RESTful is not mandatory.  Are you sure that the RESTful WS you are consuming really populate the WADL?  If not, then there is probably nothing you can do for it.

Comment: And REST tends not to be to dogmatic about the makeup of the "parameters" meaning that WADL does not include the payloads etc

Comment: @AdrianShum This is my another concern is it feasible to create a WDAL for REST service, because REST are differnet from SOAP nad if I create a WADL for REST then it is tightly coupled with the Consumer , later if I change anything I have to notify consumer, please assist me on the same

Comment: @KarthikPrasad so you mean to say all the REST services which I am going to consuming should be build with CXF , in all the cases my client will not provide that may be some of them are using Spring REST or Jersey. So in that scenario how ?